# Show results for mistyped searches

Tags: feature-request, search

When searching for a topic in the search box, and accidentally misspelling something, Search takes it literally and doesn't show anything.

Take a page out of Google's Playbook and say something like

User types in Rudy

"Showing results for Ruby"

Comment: SE search isn't nearly as advanced as Google search. How would it know what you meant?

Comment: Could easily do levenshein distance or some algorithm.

Comment: So if I type in "net", do I mean ".net" or "networking" or "neural-networking" or ...

Comment: more than likely .net, because of word distance

Comment: Well, here's something interesting. I guess it already does. For your [example query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rudy), it matches "Rudy" **and "Rudi"**. Now, it's not catching "ruby", which I still don't think it should though.

Comment: Levenshtein distance against what, exactly?

Comment: When I type "Rudy" into Google it has no idea I meant "Ruby" either. SE's search seems to behave in exactly the same way, as designed.

Comment: "Could easily do" - *easily*? Are you sure you're a programmer?

Comment: SO is a site that emphasizes technical accuracy, and you want to be able to be inaccurate in your search expressions and have the site compensate? If you mean to search for "Ruby" and mistype it, search again when you see you got no results because of a typo.

Comment: This is going to destroy the legitimacy of search option. People are going to bypass it and ask the same questions over and over. Answer youself if you really want that?

Comment: They already do.

Comment: Typing the wrong words into a search engine does not destroy the legitimacy of the search engine. Every tool ever invented has been misused almost immediately after its invention. That doesn't make it less useful for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I originally left this as a comment, i'll now post it as an answer:

> SE search isn't nearly as advanced as Google search. How would it know what you meant???

If you type the wrong thing, it's your own fault. SE isn't going to waste developer time and money to catch people's search typos.

Based on your comments, it seems like you haven't really thought this out too well.

---

If you think that you could do a good job with it, by all means, go ahead and write your own search correction algorithm.